# Goutte library for scraping data within Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, goutte

I am thinking of using [Goutte](https://goutte.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?ref=hackernoon.com) PHP library for scraping data within **Facebook API**.

I was wondering, if is it possible to access their scrape api endpoint. Can I access their scrape api endpoint with this kind of library?

*Note:* I need the same result as facebook has, so I need somehow to access their endpoint so I can scrape data.

Trough [Facebook GraphApi Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v11.0) I can see it's available and that they are using a scrape api.

Is this possible with Goutte or there are other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: there is no "scrape api endpoint", scraping is not allowed on facebook, you must use the graph api (and there is an SDK for PHP, btw.). anyway, "is xyz possible" is too broad for stackoverflow, i am afraid. you need to hit the developer docs first and try stuff.